# Change Transparent Shader to Color Black (Unity)

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, shader

What I'm trying to do here is that i want to make this [hair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wG0J0.png)  to be black . I changed the Color tint on the inspector but still did not work.

Here is my code so far for my hair shader:

```
Shader "Custom/Paul/Hair" {
Properties {
_MainTex ("Base (RGB) Trans (A)", 2D) = "white" {}
_Color ("Color Tint", Color) = (1,1,1,1) 
}

SubShader {
    Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}
    LOD 100

    ZWrite off
    Lighting Off
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    Cull back

    Pass {
        CGPROGRAM

             #pragma vertex vert
             #pragma fragment frag
             #pragma multi_compile_fog

             #include "UnityCG.cginc"

             struct appdata_t {
                 float4 vertex : POSITION;
                 float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
             };

             struct v2f {
                 float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
                 half2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                 UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
                 half4 color: COLOR;
             };

             sampler2D _MainTex;
             float4 _MainTex_ST;

             v2f vert (appdata_t v)
             {
                 v2f o;
                 o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                 o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                 UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
                 return o;
             }

             fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
             {
                 fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord);
                 //fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.texcoord) * _Color;
                 UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
                 return col;
             }
        ENDCG
    }
  }
}
```

I tried changing the color tint color in the properties but it doesn't change the color of the hair. Is there a way to change the hair color dynamically in the shader properties, even not in the shader properties even just on the code only . Sorry for my bad english.

And one more thing . I don't get any errors.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to change the *transparent* parts to black. Second, you didn't change the *color* to black, you changed it to *fully transparent white.*

Comment: @Draco18s I tried it sir actually but it did nothing . So i change it again to white..

Comment: Then update the image showing that you changed it to black. Saying "I want black" and having the color set to white makes us think that you've not done the blindingly obvious thing which should work (and thus have not supplied a Minimally *Complete* Verified Example).

Comment: @Draco18s Done sir

Comment: I've messed with the challenger hair shader once and it was a year ago. I remember that it did something odd with the colors, but I'm not seeing the problem at the moment...

Comment: hmmm . tried changing this `Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent"}` to `Tags {"Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Opaque"}` and it does change the color of the hair to black . but the problem i can't get the spiky edges of my hair like this white looks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this instead.

```
Shader "Custom/Paul/Hair" {


Properties
{
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _Color("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
}
SubShader
{
    Tags{ "Queue" = "AlphaTest" "RenderType" = "TransparentCutout" "IgnoreProjector" = "True" }
    LOD 100

    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    ZWrite off
    Lighting Off
    Cull back

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM

        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            half2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        float4 _MainTex_ST;
        sampler2D _MainTex;
        fixed4 _Color;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o = (v2f)0;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
            o.uv = v.uv;
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv) * _Color;
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

This might help to other people who faces the same problem as mine.